# Why does my Python script run forever?

Tags: python, math, fibonacci

Here is the code:

```
numbers = [1, 2]
while new < 1000:
    new = 0
    x = int(len(numbers) - 1)
    new = numbers[x] + numbers[x-1]
    if new % 2 == 0:
        numbers.append(new)
    new += 1
print sum(numbers)
```

What did I do wrong?
Criticism is welcome. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is this the current code. Instead of running for ever your script would baulk at while new< 1000 because new is undefined at that point. On a side note lots of  programers avoid the use of 'new' as a variable name because it's a keyword in many languages.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to get sum of even fibonacci numbers?

Comment: `new` is always `3` so is always less than `1000`.

Comment: If you're not going to learn to use a debugger, at least use some print statements to see where your program is not doing what you think it's doing.  [Running to SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32804984/2336725) as your first step in debugging will not go over well.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically because of the following condition -

```
if new % 2 == 0:
```

coupled with the line - `new=number[x] + number[x-1]` at the start of the loop.

The first fibonacci number you calculate is `3` , because of the above condition , it is never actually added to `number` , and hence in every loop you are again calculating the same `1+2` , since `number` is never actually changed.

The issue is not because of the line - `new=0` at the start of the loop like other answer are explaining (that line has no effect at all , you can remove it and see same results).

If your aim is to get the list of all even fibonacci numbers, then you can do -

```
numbers = [2]
a, b = 1, 2
while b < 1000:
    x = int(len(numbers) - 1)
    a, b = b, a+b
    if b % 2 == 0:
        numbers.append(b)
print sum(numbers)
```

Demo -

```
>>> numbers = [2]
>>> a, b = 1, 2
>>> while b < 1000:
...     x = int(len(numbers) - 1)
...     a, b = b, a+b
...     if b % 2 == 0:
...         numbers.append(b)
...
>>> print(sum(numbers))
798
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that nothing really gets updated.

```
numbers = [1, 2]
while new < 1000:
    new = 0  #you're resetting new here
    x = int(len(numbers) - 1)
    new = numbers[x] + numbers[x-1] # first iteration, gives 3
    if new % 2 == 0:  # 3 % 2 != 0, so it doesn't get run
        numbers.append(new)
    new += 1 # great, new is now 1.
print sum(numbers)
```

Every iteration of the loop runs like this because nothing ever changes. If you wanted to do fibonacci, you would do something like this

```
numbers = [1, 2]
for _ in range(1000)
    n = numbers[-1] + numbers[-2] # use negative indices to count from the end.
    numbers.append(n)
print sum(numbers) # sum of fibonacci I guess
```

Answer (score -1):

Every time you add one to the variable `new` in your loop, you set it back to `0` when you reiterate the loop! This means that `new` will never reach 1000--it will continue forever in the loop.

To fix this, move the initialization of `new` outside of the loop.

Comment: Did you try running this? (Not the downvoter though).

Comment: @AnandSKumar just tried it. to be honest, i assumed the infinite loop was the problem, and the rest of the program was fine.